# How can I run a pipeline with a yaml template that refers to a variables file in a different repo with Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

I have repo A that holds pipeline templates.  Repo A has the following azure-template.yml:

```
# Repo A / azure-template.yml

stages:
- stage: ${{ variables.stageName }} 
  jobs:
    - job:
      steps:
        - task:
```

A lot of the code in repo A that has the templates refers to variables in the following format:
${{ variables.variableName }}.  The variable file is in a different folder in repo A.  (e.g. variables/variables.yaml)

Now let's move to repo B.  Repo B has my azure-pipeline.yml that needs to build from repo A:

```
# Repo B / azure-pipeline.yml

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      name: repoA
      ref:  refs/heads/develop

variables:
- template: variables/variables.yml@templates

stages:
- template: azure-template.yml@templates  # Template reference
```

When I run azure-pipeline.yml, I get the following error:

**An error occurred while loading the YAML build pipeline. The string must have at least one character. Parameter name: environmentName**

That parameter is not one of mine.  I don't have it declared or set anywhere.  This tells me it is Azure specific but I have no idea where/why it's there or where it is even set.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I run a pipeline with a yaml template that refers to a
>   variables file in a different repo with Azure DevOps?

You're in correct direction, at least a working direction. It's supported to do that like what you've done above. About the error you got, I assume there could be something wrong with your yaml syntax. You can try following steps to locate the issue:

1. Copy the content of `azure-template.yml` and `variables.yaml` directly into `azure-pipeline.yml` file, and run the pipeline again to check if the issue persists.
2. In your Azure-pipeline.yml, specify the `trigger` and `pool`.
3. In `azure-template.yml`, try replacing the `${{ variables.stageName }}` with hard-code value.

This is my first time to see this error message, but according to `Parameter name: environmentName`.You can also check if [Release.EnvironmentName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell#release-variables) has valid value in one PS task. Hope it helps :)

Comment: It started as a large working yaml file that worked.  I just cut and paste pieces from the working file to different files.

I tried including the variables in the azure-pipelines.yaml directly with a link to the stage (what you suggested in #1) - I even kept everything in 1 repo just to see if that was an issue - same error. 

I have a trigger specified.  Replacing variables with hard coded values defeats my purpose.  

I suspect my issue is in this one: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/6513

Comment: Maybe it's same issue as you suspect, but I'm not sure about this. Could you reproduce same issue if you create a new minimal sample(new project with repos in similar relationships). If so, I assume there's something wrong with how you define the yaml. Cause if i use same content like what in your  question, all works well... If this is reproducible in a minimal sample, share the sample yaml here, we can check for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error. Let me explain my use case, which might help you.

This error appears in Template2.yml, but not in Template1.yml. So it looks like that there are certain places in the YAML, such as demands and tags, where we cannot use ${{variables.*}}. Instead, we need to modify it to accept that value as a parameter and then use ${{parameters.*}} in the templates.

**Template1.yml (parameters.DemandName)** [--> Validation: OK ]

```
parameters:
- name: DemandName
  type: string

stages:

- stage: Stage_Run_UnitTests_ABC
  displayName: 'Run UnitTests ABC'

  jobs:
  - job: Job_Run_UnitTests_ABC
    displayName: 'Run UnitTests ABC'
    timeoutInMinutes: 0
    cancelTimeoutInMinutes: 1
    pool:
      name: ReleasePool
      demands:
        - ReleaseDefinitionName -equals ${{ parameters.DemandName }}
    steps:
    - template: '../../../Steps/Steps.Get.HardwareInfo.yml'
```

**Template2.yml (variables.DemandName)** [--> An error occurred while loading the YAML build pipeline. The string must have at least one character. Parameter name:value]

```
stages:

- stage: Stage_Run_UnitTests_ABC
  displayName: 'Run UnitTests ABC'

  jobs:
  - job: Job_Run_UnitTests_ABC
    displayName: 'Run UnitTests ABC'
    timeoutInMinutes: 0
    cancelTimeoutInMinutes: 1
    pool:
      name: ReleasePool
      demands:
        - ReleaseDefinitionName -equals ${{ variables.DemandName }}
    steps:
    - template: '../../../Steps/Steps.Get.HardwareInfo.yml'
```